# How to get/load Yjs Doc via websocket

Tags: websocket, ws

I'm trying to get/load Y.Doc via WebSocket API (y-websocket library).

For this I wrote simple code like this. It connects to the server, but I can't load a document.

```
const id = 'my doc id';
const accessToken = 'my tocken';
const endpoint = `${WEBSOCKET_BASE}/document/${id}/`;
const params = accessToken ? { at: accessToken } : undefined;

let doc = new Doc();
doc.autoLoad = true;

const websocketProvider = new WebsocketProvider(endpoint, '', doc, {
    connect: false,
    params,
    WebSocketPolyfill: WebSocket,
});

websocketProvider.on('status', ({ status }: any) => {
    console.log('Status is' + status.toString());
});

websocketProvider.on('synced', () => {
    channel.printLine('Synced');
   
    console.log('is doc loaded: ' + doc.isLoaded.toString());
    console.log('is doc synced ' + doc.isSynced.toString());

    console.log(doc.getText());
});

websocketProvider.on('reload', (doc: Doc) => {
    console.log('reaload');
});    

doc.whenLoaded.then(() => {
    console.log('loaded now');
});

websocketProvider.connect();
```

Maybe someone knows how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can connect your ydoc with websocket provider, like so:

```
import * as Y from "yjs";
import { WebsocketProvider } from "y-websocket";

const doc = new Y.Doc();
const wsProvider = new WebsocketProvider(
  "wss://demos.yjs.dev",
  "my-roomname",
  doc
);

wsProvider.on("status", (event) => {
  console.log(event.status); // logs "connected" or "disconnected"
});
```

You can add the other event listeners on wsProvider object.

I am adding a full working demo here, for you reference:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <button id="button">Insert random number to array</button>
      <div id="result" />
    </div>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
import * as Y from "yjs";
import { WebsocketProvider } from "y-websocket";

const doc = new Y.Doc();
const wsProvider = new WebsocketProvider(
  "wss://demos.yjs.dev",
  "my-roomname",
  doc
);

wsProvider.on("status", (event) => {
  console.log(event.status); // logs "connected" or "disconnected"
});

const yarray = doc.getArray("my-array");

const button = document.getElementById("button");
const resultDiv = document.getElementById("result");

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const randomNumberBetweenZeroAndTen = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  yarray.push([randomNumberBetweenZeroAndTen]);
});

resultDiv.innerText = "Content of my-array: " + yarray.toArray();
yarray.observe(() => {
  resultDiv.innerText = "Content of my-array: " + yarray.toArray();
});
```

[codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-tu-j32ltg?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js%3A0-302)

The above implementation will sync your ydoc between two clients via websocket.